# Extending an isomorphism to $F[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

In chapter 13 of Dummit/Foote (p.518 to be more precise) the authors mention that if $\phi: F \to F'$ is an isomorphism, then $\phi$ induces a ring isomorphism 
\begin{equation*}
\tilde{\phi}: F[x] \to F'[x]
\end{equation*}
defined by applying $\phi$ to the coefficients of $f(x) \in F[x]$.

Now it may be that the authors have explained this concept somewhere else in the text and I have just not realized it, but it seems to me that this statement is far from trivial and really deserves to be a theorem.   This statement also raises a few questions for me:

1. I'm guessing the phrase "applying $\phi$ to the coefficients of $f(x)$" means I write $f(x)$ in the form 
   \begin{equation*}
   f(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1x + a_0
   \end{equation*}
   and then apply $\phi$ to the $a_i$.  But what if $f(x)$ is written in the form 
   \begin{equation*}
   f(x) = p(x)q(x)
   \end{equation*}
   Then will I get the same thing if I apply $\phi$ to the coefficients of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ separately? In other words, do we have:
   \begin{equation*}
   \tilde{\phi}\big(a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1x + a_0\big) = \tilde{\phi}\big(p(x)\big) \tilde{\phi}\big(q(x)\big)
   \end{equation*}
   Since $\tilde{\phi}$ is a homomorphism, these should be the same.  This leads to my second question:
2. If it does not matter how I factor $f(x)$ before applying $\tilde{\phi}$, then we need to show that $\tilde{\phi}$ is well-defined.  This seems to be very nontrivial, because there are many different factorizations of a given polynomial.  Do you know an outline of a proof for this result?
3. What if I factor $f(x) \in F[x]$ into $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$, where the coefficients of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ live in some bigger field extension of $F$, i.e. $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are not in $F[x]$.  Then I'm guessing I can't apply $\tilde{\phi}$ to this factorization of $f(x)$, right?  This seems kind of  strange to me.

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: I think your 2. is "does $\tilde\phi$ preserve multiplication?"

Comment: Perhaps is that I'm used to this kind of stuff but I think this is reasonably trivial (or maybe I'm missing something here). True, something must be proved, but the most important fact is that $\;\phi\;$ is a fields isomorphism. You may want first to apply this to irreducible polynomials, and then check it extends nicely to products of irred. polynomials...and you're done. And of course that if some poly. is factorizable in some bigger field then you cannot apply the given rings hom. to the coeffcients in that bigger field...I don't see anything odd in that.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  Not really.  I think question (2) is really: Is $\tilde{\phi}$ well-defined?  If I could show that $\tilde{\phi}$ is well-defined, then $\tilde{\phi}$ being multiplicative is believable to me.

Comment: @SamY. We'll have to agree to differ then.

Comment: @DonAntonio  Thanks for your comment about the irreducibles...I will think about that.  I guess why I think the situation I described in (3) is odd is because of the following:  Suppose I have $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$, where $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ do not live in $F[x]$.  Then it seems odd to me that I can apply $\tilde{\phi}$ to the left hand side of this equation, but I can't apply it to the RHS.

Comment: @SamY. That may happen in several instances. For example, you may have a homomorphism of groups, or rings, defined on $\;\Bbb Z\;$ , and the fact that you can write, say $\;1=\frac25\cdot\frac52\;$ doesn't say you can apply this *integers* homomorphism on the rational non-integers $\;\frac25,\,\frac52\;$ ...I don't find this specially curious or weird.

Comment: @DonAntonio  You are right.  Good point.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\phi:R\to R'$ be a ring homomorphism. Then $\phi$ induces a ring homomorphism $(\cdot)^\phi:R[X]\to R'[X]$ on the corresponding polynomial rings by

$$\sum_{k=0}^n a_kX^k\mapsto \sum_{k=0}^n\phi(a_k)X^k.$$

**Example:** Reducing an integral polynomial modulo some prime number to see whether or not it's irreducible is quite popular.

1. **Hint:** Use the so-called convolution product notation:$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^na_kX^k \right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^mb_kX^k\right)= \sum_{k=0}^{n+m}\left(\sum_{i+j=k}a_ib_j X^k\right)$$
2. The representation of an $f(X)\in R[X]$ as a linear combination of monic monomials $X^k$ is unique, and the image of $(\cdot)^\phi$ is immediately in its target space. Hence $(\cdot)^\phi$ is well-defined.
3. Indeed, but often you will extend $\phi$ to have the extension field as the domain (quite possibly this extension will not be unique, which is where the fun part begins really) and use the same machinery to that extension to transport factors to some other polynomial ring (e.g. to the polynomial ring over some algebraically closed field that contains the initial field).

Comment: Good, +1. I think your observation that multiplication comes out of the convolution process is the key to resolving OP’s confusion.